# How to Host laravel 5.2 on CENTOS server

Tags: laravel, centos, hosting, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I am trying to host my laravel 5.2 project on a CENTOS Server (Shared Hosting) I followed this tutorial 
https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

but when I try running it on online I get a blank page.
I checked my log I got this error

AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

I then followed this http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-error-no-matching-directoryindex-index-html-found-solved/ to solve that but I still keep getting a blank page with the same error in the log.

Please any help will be so much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which folder on the server you have deployed your Laravel app?

Answer (score 0):

You should point web server to a public directory inside Laravel project directory, not to it's root.

Answer (score 0):

I had to redirect apache in the host file to the project folder